# C++ Eclipse really remove deleted file

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am working on an eclipse c++ project and I got into a situation where it seemed the only way forward was to delete a class.  I have done this before and it seems to work.  After I deleted the file I tried to recreate it and eclipse tells me the file still exists.

When I use index/rebuild then I look at the c++ Index view it is still there.  From the index view I can open the definition of the class.

How can I really delete the file, or how can I get it back so I can just move it out of the source directory?

Comment: "From the index view I can open the definition of the class." As in you can display the file in the editor? If so, are you certain you deleted the correct file and Eclipse isn't playing silly games with where the files are relative to where the workspace is?

Comment: I don't know how to check if that is true, I think maybe in the project meta files there is some copy of the file used for code analysis that didn't get deleted.  I solved the problem by creating the class files elsewhere and then copy them to the directory.  After I refreshed the directory it was all correct.  Just one more of Eclipse many defects :)

Comment: When you deleted the file did you delete if from Eclipse or outside eclipse? If outside eclipse, make a new file of the same name in the same place with another tool and see what happens when you try to open it in eclipse.

Comment: I deleted it from eclipse.  After trying everything I could think of, I created the class outside of eclipse and copied the file into the right place. Everything seems good now.